# Docker command can start a mysql container, but docker-compose.yml can't, what are possible causes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to start a mysql container using centos/mysql-56-centos7 image. There are two ways:

1)

```
docker run -d --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456  centos/mysql-56-centos7
```

this way works fine

2) docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: centos/mysql-56-centos7:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
```

and in the .env file, I set

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
```

but the starting always fails:

```
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                            COMMAND                             CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
b651a67ae0b310a7e08ac20919c08583e50a2dc9f515a16618c4db130ea65415   centos/mysql-56-centos7:latest   "container-entrypoint run-mysqld"   55 seconds ago      Restarting (1) 25 seconds ago                       mysql
```

logs info

```
mysql    | => sourcing 20-validate-variables.sh ...
mysql    | You must either specify the following environment variables:
mysql    |   MYSQL_USER (regex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$')
mysql    |   MYSQL_PASSWORD (regex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9_~!@#$%^&*()-=<>,.?;:|]+$')
mysql    |   MYSQL_DATABASE (regex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$')
mysql    | Or the following environment variable:
mysql    |   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD (regex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9_~!@#$%^&*()-=<>,.?;:|]+$')
mysql    | Or both.
mysql    | Optional Settings:
mysql    |   MYSQL_LOWER_CASE_TABLE_NAMES (default: 0)
mysql    |   MYSQL_LOG_QUERIES_ENABLED (default: 0)
mysql    |   MYSQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS (default: 151)
mysql    |   MYSQL_FT_MIN_WORD_LEN (default: 4)
mysql    |   MYSQL_FT_MAX_WORD_LEN (default: 20)
mysql    |   MYSQL_AIO (default: 1)
mysql    |   MYSQL_KEY_BUFFER_SIZE (default: 32M or 10% of available memory)
mysql    |   MYSQL_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET (default: 200M)
mysql    |   MYSQL_TABLE_OPEN_CACHE (default: 400)
mysql    |   MYSQL_SORT_BUFFER_SIZE (default: 256K)
mysql    |   MYSQL_READ_BUFFER_SIZE (default: 8M or 5% of available memory)
mysql    |   MYSQL_INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE (default: 32M or 50% of available memory)
mysql    |   MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE (default: 8M or 15% of available memory)
mysql    |   MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE (default: 8M or 15% of available memory)
mysql    | 
mysql    | For more information, see https://github.com/sclorg/mysql-container
```

I think these two ways are equivalent, but they first succeeds while the second fails, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Docker Compose example, you're not actually setting the environment variable.  You need to add it explicitly:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: centos/mysql-56-centos7:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    # restart: always  # once it's actually working
```

The `.env` file [makes values available for substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) within the `docker-compose.yml` file, but doesn't automatically inject them into containers.  You need an [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) section.  If you just list a variable name, it gets the value from the environment (the documentation doesn't explicitly say "or a `.env` file" but I think it should work).